# How should the script tag in a react page be written to include it properly with webpack?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, node-modules, webpack-dev-server

I am trying to include react in my HTML page. At first I tried like this:

```
<script src="js/custom/custom.js"></script>
```

But that syntax gives me the following error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

So I added the module attribute:

```
<script type="module" src="js/custom/custom.js"></script>
```

But with that, webpack isn't  able to resolve the [module path](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/module-resolution/#module-paths) correctly, giving me this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "react". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".

I have set up webpack with a custom entry path like so:

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    entry: './js/custom/custom.js',
    output: {
        path:  path.join(__dirname, '/build'),
        publicPath: '/',
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    },
    devServer: {
        contentBase: path.join(__dirname, '/'),
        port: 9000
    },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that that script element is pointing to the raw, uncompiled source script, instead of the output script which webpack generates. It needs to point to webpack's output script so that it will be run through babel, compiled, compressed, etc.

The correct path to webpack's output script is the dev server address, plus the filename specified in `webpack.config.js` output filename. Thus, if config looks like:

```
module.exports = {
    output: {
        filename: 'badoongy-face.js'
    },
```

Then the script tag should be:

`<script src="https://localhost:8000/badoongy-face.js"></script>`

or the same thing as a relative path:

`<script src="badoongy-face.js"></script>`

Comment: Are you the author of 'badoongy-face'?

Answer (score 0):

`html-webpack-plugin` is thing you need

check [this](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/html-webpack-plugin/) out

> The plugin will generate an HTML5 file for you that includes all your webpack bundles in the body using script tags. Just add the plugin to your webpack configuration as follows:

```
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
var path = require('path');

...
plugins: [new HtmlWebpackPlugin()]
..
```

[Check how you can add custom template](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cKTDYSK0ArI)

Comment: You should mention in your answer that using this plugin without the `template` option generates a boilerplate html file.

Comment: Feel free to improve the answer, and there is a link to add custom template and the document say all the stuffs

Comment: So is the idea here that this plugin will generate an HTML file with the correct <script>  syntax  that I can then copy/paste into my actual file?

Comment: It looks like it creates the HTML file when building, but not during development. I am trying to get this to work in development.

Comment: It should work same as production, but double check you have it in development config of webpack, To get the idea behind this check the youtube tutorial that i  have linked\